# How to maximize regression coefficient instead of factor loadings in SEM?

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, factor-rotation

I wonder if there is a method that allows finding factor loadings so that the factor would predict the distal outcome the best? The ordinary SEM model would estimate factor loadings and regression coefficients independently of each other, but I have a little interest in the factor itself, I am interested in this factor only in the relation to this external variable. I think it could be something like a target rotation method, where the target is the set of loadings that produce the factor that results in the largest regression coefficient.

To make it more clear I give an example. I have a factor representing cognitive abilities with 20 indicators, and the specific observed outcome variable - job performance. The ordinary SEM would try to fit factor model to a covariance of indicators, representing it best. Instead, I would like to see a factor that predicts job performance best and I don't really care about the quality of the factor model itself, except for it should reproduce in the other samples.

Comment: What purpose does the factor serve in your example? Why not just remove the factor and regress directly on the items?  Then create a factor using the predicted values from the regression.

Comment: I added a comment below. My real purpose isn't a prediction by itself, but finding the factor loadings that comply with an external validity criterion.

Answer (score 2):

As Jeremy mentioned in the comments, if your goal is prediction, then there is no sense in creating an interpretable factor. You can use flexible regression or machine learning methods directly on the items. Adding a factor structure only limits the relationship between the items and the outcome by imposing independence constraints, which seem unnecessary to suit your goals. The goal of SEM is to test a constrained covariance structure among the the observed variables and estimate the parameters that minimize the difference between the constrained and observed covariance structures. If your goal is optimal prediction, none of that is relevant, and SEM is not the tool you should use.

Indeed, going down your road, you can construct a silly example that demonstrates the absurdity of using SEM to optimize prediction of an outcome. In your SEM, simply constrain the error variance of the outcome to be 0, the factor loadings to all be 0, and the mean and variance of the factor to be the mean and variance of your outcome. Your estimated coefficient will be 1, and the factor will have an R2 of 1.0, perfect prediction. Does this satisfy your desiderata? It's a factor whose relationship with the indicators is unimportant and it predicts the outcome extremely (i.e. perfectly) well. Clearly this is problematic.

The point is that with SEM, you can devise any constraints to satisfy your desires, but the goal of SEM is not to maximize prediction; rather, its very purpose is to reproduce the population covariance matrix of the observed variables with model constraints. It simply is not the tool for your job.

Comment: Thanks, you have clarified it a lot. My real purpose was to find a factor structure that satisfies the external validity criteria (not a prediction by itself). I think, your suggestion of constraining the residual of the outcome to zero is not a total absurd. I guess maybe instead of a constraint I can take a Bayesian perspective and substitute constraint with a small prior?